# Revolving an unknown equation around the x and y axes

Tags: integration, rotations

The first quadrant region enclosed by the x-axis and the graph of ***y = ax - x^2*** traces out a solid of the same volume whether it is rotated about the x-axis or the y-axis. What is the value of ***a***?

Comment: Rotate about the $x$-axis. That should be routine. Rotate about the $y$-axis. I suggest using cylindrical shells. Set the answers equal, and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\pi\int_0^a (ax-x^2)^2dx= 2\pi\int_0^ax(ax-x^2)dx$$

The upper bound of integration of both integrals is $a$ because that is where the function will cross the x-axis (assuming $a>0$).

Comment: After integrating using this formula, I got a = 5. Is that correct?